# Recursive function causing stack overflow

Tags: c, windows, recursion

I have a bit of code that is working except it is causing a stack overflow. I know the issue is caused because of recursion but I am not sure what I can do to stop it in this scenario.

The Code:

```
void FindFilesRecursively(LPCTSTR lpFolder) {
    TCHAR szFullPattern[MAX_PATH];
    WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
    HANDLE hFindFile;

    PathCombine(szFullPattern, lpFolder, (L"*"));
    hFindFile = FindFirstFile(szFullPattern, &FindFileData);
    if (wcscmp(FindFileData.cFileName, L".") == 0){
        FindNextFile(hFindFile, &FindFileData);
        if (wcscmp(FindFileData.cFileName, L"..") == 0) {
            FindNextFile(hFindFile, &FindFileData);
        }
    }
    if (hFindFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        do {
            if (FindFileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) {
                // found a subdirectory; recurse into it
                PathCombine(szFullPattern, lpFolder, FindFileData.cFileName);
                printf("FOLDER: %S\n", szFullPattern);
                FindFilesRecursively(szFullPattern);
            }
            printf("FILE: %S\n", FindFileData.cFileName);
        } while (FindNextFile(hFindFile, &FindFileData));
        FindClose(hFindFile);
    }
    printf("END\n");
}
```

Basically all it does it takes a folder/file path as argument and then it will print the name if it is a folder, or it will go recursively through the path and print everything. My debugger is hitting stack overflow at about 53 calls to this function. I am not sure where/how I should terminate a call to this function so that it doesn't cause the stack overflow.

Comment: Fyi, the checks fro `'.'` and `'..'` and an subsequent ignoring of said-same should be part of the loop; not assumed to optionally be the first (or first two) entries. As soon as the latter assumption fails, the entire loop will recurse indefinitely.

Comment: Take action on the value of `hFindFile` *immediately*: you are executing code based on the supposed data in `FindFileData` in between.

Comment: What is `MAX_PATH`

Comment: 260, its not coming close to that.

Comment: hmmm 53 times (260 plus a little) shouldn't cause stack overflow

Comment: For debug I'll suggest you print the addres of e.g. `szFullPattern` to see how much the stack increase between each call.

Comment: "If the function fails, the return value is zero and the contents of `lpFindFileData` are indeterminate." I suggest you have a single loop, which ignores `"."` and `".."`.

Comment: Recursion in languages which don't support tail recursion can be problematic because on stack-based machines you'll eventually run out of stack space, which is what appears to be happening here. Your best bet is to rewrite this to use a loop rather than recursion.

Comment: BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica Yes thats exactly what is happening. I took advice from @WhozCraig and I was able to calm the recursion down to only the depth of the file structure. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

When your code hits empty directory, it will backtrack to parent directory:

```
if (wcscmp(FindFileData.cFileName, L"..") == 0) {
        FindNextFile(hFindFile, &FindFileData);
    }
}
if (hFindFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
```

FindNextFile returns zero if no more entries, but your code doesn't check for it. Since hFindFile is not INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, your code happily processes cached ".." as next found entry, but it will redirect to parent folder (and eventually produce SO). Here is the fixed code:

```
    void FindFilesRecursively(LPCTSTR lpFolder) {
    TCHAR szFullPattern[MAX_PATH];
    WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
    HANDLE hFindFile;

    PathCombine(szFullPattern, lpFolder, (L"*"));
    hFindFile = FindFirstFile(szFullPattern, &FindFileData);
    if (hFindFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        do {
            if ((FindFileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) != 0 && 
                wcscmp(FindFileData.cFileName, L".") != 0 && 
                wcscmp(FindFileData.cFileName, L"..") != 0) {
                // found a subdirectory, and it's neither .. nor ..; recurse into it
                PathCombine(szFullPattern, lpFolder, FindFileData.cFileName);
                printf("FOLDER: %S\n", szFullPattern);
                FindFilesRecursively(szFullPattern);
            }
            printf("FILE: %S\n", FindFileData.cFileName);
        } while (FindNextFile(hFindFile, &FindFileData));
        FindClose(hFindFile);
    }
    printf("END\n");
}
```